# vimeo api python using keywords to search for videos

Tags: python, api, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm trying to use the Vimeo API with Python, but I'm stuck trying to find video's using keywords.

What I have is this, after successfully registering with Vimeo:

```
import vimeo

client = vimeo.VimeoClient(
  token='my_token',
  key='my_key',
  secret='my_secret_key'
)
about_me = client.get('/me',params={'fields':'uri,name'})
json.loads(about_me.text)
```

these return my user credentials. Now I want to use a similar approach to get videos using Query keywords, like on [their page](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos?version=3.4#search_videos). But I cannot get it to work.
So, I want to have a JSON returned with movies based on keywords (like 'interstellar trailer' and not the URI or id of Vimeo).
But for some reason, I can't get the query keyword to work, and from the linked page above, I cannot figure it out how to implement it in my code.

27-02-19: UPDATE: I figured it out, and will update my solution here, soon.

Comment: You should probably replace `/me` with the full URL `https://api.vimeo.com/me`.

Answer (score 0):

The `/me` [endpoint](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/users#get_user) only returns the user object for the authenticated user.

To get and search for videos, use the `/me/videos` or `/videos` [endpoint](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos?version=3.4#search_videos) (depending on if you are searching for videos on your own account, or searching for videos from other users public on Vimeo).